# Message hub service going down everyday

Tags: ibm-cloud, message-hub

Iam using bluemix message hub service in my node app which is in production.Now we have run in to an issue that message hub service goes down everyday and the app needs to be restarted then.This cant be done so.
We are getting the following logs

```
2016-10-16T17:41:42.66+0100 [App/0] OUT Unable to consume topic: Error: Request returned
status code 404 but it was not in the accepted list. The REST API responded with the 
following message: Consumer instance not found.
2016-10-16T17:41:46.66+0100 [App/0] OUT got error: { [Error: Request returned status code 
404 but it was not in the accepted list. The REST API responded with the following message:
Consumer instance not found.] statusCode: 404, errorCode: 40403 }
```

Is there any way that we can handle this.This is failing over here

```
 run: function(callback) {         
                    var that = this;
                    consumerInstance.get(topic)
                        .then(function(data) {
                            that.consume(data);
                            return callback();
                        })
                        .fail(function(error) {
                            console.log("got error: ", error);
                            return callback(error);
                        })
                }
```

This is the code which we are using for reference

https://github.com/ibm-cds-labs/Spark-Twitter-Watson-Dashboard/blob/master/server/messageHubBridge.js?s_tact=C43301PW

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue.
Thanks,
Harish.

Answer (score 2):

Hi the REST endpoint for MessageHub gets recycled every 24 hours.
Clients are expected to handle this by creating a new consumer instance.

HTH, 
Edo

Comment: Thanks.can u give some insight on how can we create so.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Message Hub documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/MessageHub/index.html#messagehub057), the REST service restarts daily. After the REST API has restarted, you will have to recreate your Kafka consumer instances.

Thanks,

Simon.